# How to set states inside ifcondition in functional component

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-functional-component, react-state

How to set `setEditOnClick(true)` on condition inside functional component

```
const peopleCard = () => {
 const [isEditOnclick, setEditOnClick] = useState(false);
 const [peopleID, setpeopleID] = useState('');
return (
.....
.....some other code
.....

 {isEditOnclick ? 

    <CrudModal id={peopleID} />
    {setEditOnClick(false)}
     
    : null }

}

......
......
 <button onMouseEnter={() => setEditOnClick(true)}}
```

Am new to react kindly help me to fix this

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. From the snippet of code it looks like you're trying to make it so when you set the state to true, it immediately gets reset to false. So the crudModal would show for the briefest moment, and then immediately disappear. Could you describe what the intended benefit of this is?

Comment: Updating the state causes a rerender. So even if it was possible inside the rendering, it doesn't make any sense because that part of the rendering will be visible for a very short period of time only (if at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not set the state 'setEditOnClick(true)' inside your JSX code because you are basically unrendering the CrudModal component. Instead, you should do the following:

```
    const PeopleCard = () => {
      const [isEditOnclick, setEditOnClick] = useState(false);
      const [peopleID, setpeopleID] = useState('');
    
      // Define a function to handle the mouse enter event on the button
      // Check if isEditOnclick is currently false
      // Set isEditOnclick to true using the setEditOnClick function
      const handleMouseEnter = () => {
        if (!isEditOnclick) {
          setEditOnClick(true);
        }
      };
    
      // Render the component's JSX code
      return (
        <>
          {/* some other code */}
          {isEditOnclick && <CrudModal id={peopleID} />}
          {/* some other code */}
          <button onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}>Edit</button>
        </>
      );
    };
```